# Know the average of disk used in GCE

Tags: monitor, google-cloud-platform

i have a new instance in GCE and after some days i migrate my websites and now are running in GCE.

I like to know what amount of disk i have available in GCE.

I used the monitor tools but i not found the information only found the total volume of the disk but not the amount of size the disk used or the available.. it's posible?

Comment: `gcloud ssh` to your VM and use `df` and/or `du` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of storage you have available to your project is determined by the resource quota in place, which in turn is determined by the project's billing. This could be:

Free trial - GB of PD: 10240 - quota can not be modified - more info here [1](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/)

Billing enabled - Standard PD total GB: 5120; SSD PD total GB: 1024; Local SSD total GB: 1500 - quota can be increased upon request. More info here [2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas)

By default, linux VMs deploy with a 10 GB disk, unless an already existing disk was used; the default is 100 GB for Windows machines.